# `Route`, `Switch` will re-mount child component if and only if i set process.env.NODE_ENV==='production'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

### Version

- "react": "^15.6.1",
- "redux": "^3.7.2",
- "react-router": "^4.2.0",
- "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",

### Steps to reproduce

```
// main.js

<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={history}>
    <App>
      <Switch>
        <Redirect key='index' from='/' exact to='home'/>
        {
          _.map(routes, (route, i) => {
            const {store, path, component, exact, redirectTo} = route;
            if (redirectTo) {
              return <Redirect key={path} path={path} to={redirectTo}/>;
            }
            let routeConfig = {
              path,
              exact,
              render: props => {
                return (
                  <RouteBundle load={component}>
                    {Comp => Comp ? (<Comp {...props} />) : null}
                  </RouteBundle>
                );
              }
            };

            return <Route key={path} {...routeConfig}/>;
          })
        }
        <Route key='notFound' component={NotFound}/>
      </Switch>
    </App>
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

For Route component will create new instance of child components, it comes to Endless Loop repaint by browser. I knew the BUG caused by wrong position of `<App>` component.

BUT, only when the value of  `process.env.NODE_ENV` is **production**, the BUG reproduce. WHY???

```
// in webpack file

new webpack.DefinePlugin({'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')}),
```

Comment: your Route components are missing `path` props. how will it now when to load which route?

Comment: @azium sorry, I missed the ```path``` prop here.

Comment: @azium i ve alread pasted full code

Comment: what's RouteBundle?

Comment: @azium the HOC for code spliting https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/code-splitting